# Create an advanced search with filter

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I'm looking sphinx and discovered a way to set up filters by one or more criteria.
 I'll get a database of recipes.

In the pastry, I have a table "records".
 I have cards for every type field is an integer.
 I also have a field "kind" and finally a last field called "ingredients".

I'm looking for several things.
 For the following example I have this database, which works but is not complete: 
http://pastebin.com/80LbtnZW 
 and this is my sphinx.conf: http://pastebin.com/Nmpci1aC 
 I would first like to show my field type only in descending order of id, what should I
 add?
 I would now add a filter and take only the chocolates that are kind = 2.
 And finally the same thing, with an additional filter ingredients = 'milk'

What should I add as a filter to sort by id, and thereafter, to establish one or more
 filters.

Comment: `In the pastry, I have a table "records". I have cards for every type field is an integer. I also have a field "kind" and finally a last field called "ingredients".` WTF? In the pastry? What does this mean?

Comment: In my table "pastry" (Bakery) I have three fields : "records", "kind" and "ingredients".

Comment: I suggest you update your question to reflect this. As it stands this question is pretty unreadable. Please also review the formatting documentation for StackOverflow so you can make your table definitions into unordered lists etc.

Comment: Hi friend i am new to sphinx. I am getting error NO :111

Answer (score 0):

Sort by ID...

```
$sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED, '@id DESC');
```

Add filter...

```
$sphinx->SetFilter('kind', array(2));
```

You can add as many filters as you like, make sure you have delcared the fields you are filtering as attributes.

Comment: Thanks !
But I don't know why, I've this return, when I try to put SetFilter :

bool(false);

Comment: With getError I obtain this : index recipes: no such filter attribute 'type'.

Comment: make sure you do it before your query and put your whole php code on pastebin